# VBA + Macros + For each cell condition error

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, each

I would like to seek help with the codes below.

The first "IF" condition works well but the "ELSE" condition wherein I would like to skip the copy and paste function of the first condition and continue on to the loop does not function and gives me an error message that looks like this: [image]

Thank you in advance! more power to ya'll!

```
Sub IF_Loop3()

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("TablePrac[Animals]")
        If cell.Value <> "NULL" Then
            cell.Offset(0, -3).Value = cell.Value
            
        Else
        If cell.Value = " " Then
        Exit For
        
        End If
        
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: still doesnt work, it only copies the " " space value to the target cell

Comment: `ElseIf cell.Value = " " Then` (oops)

Comment: Write ```If cell.Value = " " Then``` and ```Exit For``` on the same line so you don't need to write another ```End If```. Currently you have 2 ```If``` but only 1 ```End If```, so the compiler considers the ```Next cell``` to be inside the first ```If``` statement, thus giving you the error message.

Comment: ElseIf cell.Value = " " Then Exit For
End IF

Next cell

is it like this? still it copies the space " " to the 0, 3 coordinates :(

Comment: To be clear, you want to exit the loop if ```cell.Value = " "```, and execute this line ```cell.Offset(0, -3).Value = cell.Value``` if the value isn't ```"NULL"``` ("NULL" =/= empty cell) right  ?

Comment: Yes, I want to exit the loop for it to proceed to the next cell without copying anything. Basically the function of the button is to copy the cell value if it is not null but my dilemma is some cells does have " " (1 space value) and i dont want to copy it to the (0, -3) coordinates

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each cell In Range("TablePrac[Animals]")
        If cell.Value <> "NULL" Then
            cell.Offset(0, -3).Value = cell.Value
            
        Else If cell.Value = " " Then
             Exit For
             End If ' If cell.Value = " "
        End If 'If cell.Value <> "NULL" <= you forgot this one!
    Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

New code based on your explanation:

```
Sub IF_Loop3()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("TablePrac[Animals]")
        If (cell.Value <> "NULL") and (cell.Value <> " ") Then
            cell.Offset(0, -3).Value = cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

You have two conditions to execute the copy/paste: `value <> "NULL"` and `value <> " "`. You just need to put those two conditions in the `If` test for both to be respected.

If you write `Exit For` it means the loop will break and your code will continue with the first line **after the loop**, not with the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Does not work either, but i really appreciate your help. Thank you :)

Comment: I assume this code doesn't work in a different way than your code didn't work?  If so, what is the error message or problem you're getting now?

Comment: still it copies the " " (space value) tothe (0, -3) spot

Comment: Are you sure it's a ```" "``` (only 1 space), and not ```""``` (blank string) or maybe several spaces ? It would have the same visual render (nothing written in the cell) but would be handled differently in the code.

Comment: @DamonSolidor Try to add a breakpoint at the ```If```, open the local variables window (available in 'View' tab), run the code with F5, and look at the cell's value each time the runtime hits the breakpoint. If the value is ```" "```, press F8 to run step by step and see how the code behaves. This may give some insights about the origin of your problem.

Comment: @DamonSolidor If your could also edit your question and add a screenshot of your datatable, it will certainly help !

Comment: Sure ill do this tomorrow. Thanks!

P.S it is really “ “. (1 space only) it is directly extracted from a certain database idk what is the UI of it or any business rule they have there but at first i thought its blank but i double checked and there you go a hidden 1 space in each cell